# Cron Job firing every minute for an hour at it's scheduled execution time

Tags: cron

I must have done something wrong in crontab, but I don't see what. The entry below is executing demo-off.sh once a MINUTE beginning at 10 and going till 11.

```
* 10 * * 4,6  /home/username/demo-off.sh 2> /home/username/demo-off.log
```

Here is cron.log (shortened)

```
Aug 16 10:00:01 machine-name CROND[20680]: (username) CMD (/home/username/demo-off.sh 2> /home/username/demo-off.log)
Aug 16 10:01:01 machine-name CROND[20813]: (username) CMD (/home/username/demo-off.sh 2> /home/username/demo-off.log)
Aug 16 10:02:01 machine-name CROND[20887]: (username) CMD (/home/username/demo-off.sh 2> /home/username/demo-off.log)
    ...
Aug 18 10:57:01 machine-name CROND[9690]: (username) CMD (/home/username/demo-off.sh 2> /home/username/demo-off.log)
Aug 18 10:58:01 machine-name CROND[11257]: (username) CMD (/home/username/demo-off.sh 2> /home/username/demo-off.log)
Aug 18 10:59:02 machine-name CROND[13065]: (username) CMD (/home/username/demo-off.sh 2> /home/username/demo-off.log)
```

Can someone push me in the right direction in terms of what I did wrong?

Comment: What you did wrong depends on what you wanted instead ;-)

Comment: You used a wildcard (`*` = all), in the Minute field, so all minutes during that hour match the criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't try to figure it out, I just use the handy-dandy [corntab.com](http://corntab.com) cron gui.

It says that sure enough, what you wrote will run every minute starting at 10:00 on Thursday and Saturday.

[image]

I suggest you use corntab to get what you really want - if nothing else, it's an easy way to test your cron entries.

Note: No vested interest in corntab, just a satisfied user.

Comment: Saves you a ton of thinking especially if your me :-)